# React/ES6: Trouble Importing a Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

EDIT: Pinpointed the issue: This code is causing it not to work. If I change it from this:

```js
{this.state.formVisible
          ? <Form onClick={this.hideForm}/>
          : <AddBtn onClick={this.showForm}/>
}
```

to this:

```js
<Form/>
```

it works? Why? I don't understand why I can't show and hide the form component and still have the script work???

---

I'm having trouble correctly using a script in my React app. It was working correctly when I rendered the form directly inside a component (App.js), but I moved the form over to it's own component and now render the component inside App.js, and now the imported scripts won't work.

Here's the breakdown of the two files (the script I need to run is custom.js). As you can see, importing the script into either file doesn't work, as the script is never used.

The first file that renders the "Form" component (App.js):

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
var script = require('./custom.js');
import AddBtn from './AddBtn.js';
import Form from './Form.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      formVisible: false
    };
  };
  showForm = () => {
    this.setState({formVisible: true});
  }
  hideForm = () => {
    this.setState({formVisible: false});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <h1 id="p2">Contact Book</h1>
        <form className="search">
          <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search by last name"/>
          <button type="button">Search</button>
        </form>
        {this.state.formVisible
          ? <Form onClick={this.hideForm}/>
          : <AddBtn onClick={this.showForm}/>
}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The second file that contains the form:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
var script = require('./custom.js');

class Form extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form id="addform">
                <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" required/>
                <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" required/>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required/>
                <input type="input" name="address" placeholder="address" required/>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="phone number" required/>
                <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Submit"/>
                <button type="button" id="closebtn" onClick={this.props.onClick}>Close</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

AAAAND the script itself (which doesn't really matter. I already know it works correctly.)

```js
import $ from 'jquery';

//will hold an array of people objects
var list = [];

//constructor that builds new people to add to address book
function Person(first, last, email, address, phone) { //new person constructor
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    // When the submit button is clicked, create a new person and add the values of
    // the form fields  to the properties of the object
    $("#addform")
        .submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var person = new Person($("input[name = 'fname']").val(), $("input[name = 'lname']").val(), $("input[name = 'email']").val(), $("input[name = 'address']").val(), $("input[name = 'phone']").val());
            list.push(person);
            console.log(list);
        });
});
```

Comment: What is your script supposed to do? Can you paste the code for it?

Comment: @azium There you go

Comment: what's the point of using jquery to do this? why not put that logic into your Form component, or a parent of the Form component?

Comment: @azium I mean, there isn't any point. That's just how I did it, since I'm still learning React. Putting the logic in the Form component doesn't fix the problem, though.

Comment: Your edit works because your form component will be visible on the page when the document is ready. You're not showing/hiding it like jquery `.show` or `.hide` which sets the display value from none to block. Using a ternary will actually not even put the form into the dom so `$("#addform")` will not match any elements

Comment: @azium So what's the best way of showing/hiding it in this case?

Comment: Use React, not jQuery. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on DOM nodes which is how jQuery operates, stick within the realm of React.

```
class Form extends Component {
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = new FormData(e.target)
    for (let [key, val] of data.entries()) {
      // do something with your data
      console.log(key, val);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form id="addform" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" required/>
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" required/>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required/>
        <input type="input" name="address" placeholder="address" required/>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="phone number" required/>
        <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Submit"/>
        <button type="button" id="closebtn" onClick={this.props.onClick}>Close</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This way you don't need your external script at all, or jQuery for that matter, and you can keep your conditional ternary in your parent component the way it is.